# CSS is not loading in Laravel Application

Tags: css, laravel

I am working on live Server. There is a CSS file added previously in my application. Previous CSS code is working perfectly. I added some new CSS code to that previous CSS file. Now new CSS code is not working my application.I checked through source code of browser also. But in source code my updated CSS code is not loading. I cleared cache using below commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan route:cache  
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan optimize:clear
```

But nothing is working in live Server.

How can I debug this issue ?

Comment: Probably you are using any CDN service, like cloudflare ?

Comment: Thanks @STA. No I am not using any CDN. Thanks.

Comment: Hard refresh the browser or try incognito; also make use CSS versioning to NOT run into these kind of issues

Comment: i have this problem too, maybe your css cached in browser... just add a version to your css link, like this:

    <link href="/css.css?v=1.1" />

Comment: The builder (often Laravel Mix is used) should add the version to your css link automatically. You can create a build with `npm run build`.

Comment: Thanks @Kokodoko. I am not using any builder locally. I uploaded locally developed CSS in server. `npm install` or `npm run build` is not working in this Server. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the CSS `<link>` tag in your HTML? Are you able to access the CSS file? What does your browser's network inspector show; any 404s?

Comment: The builder can be used on the local side. First you design the new CSS, then you use `laravel mix` to build, and then you upload to the server. If you don't want to use laravel mix, you can still add the version number manually. It's a bit of a hassle if you change the CSS often.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. Yes, I can see CSS tag in HTML. Yes, I am able to access the CSS file. I can see old code in CSS file. But I can't see new code which I added later. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AliRaza. I tried with versioning. But old code is working. New code is not appearing even I inspect source code.

Comment: Thanks @mohammadhosseingoli. I tried like `<link href="/css.css?v=1.1" />`. But old code is working. New code is not appearing even I inspect source code.

Comment: Thanks @Kokodoko. I am not using `laravel mix` locally. Thanks.

Comment: Laravel version? are you using vite ?

Comment: If your source is not found, then your base URL is not valid, remember that use "v" outside of asset()